# WPF xaml conditionally add control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have the following xaml structure

```
<Grid>
     <Grid x:Name="innerGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
</Grid>
```

the problem is that the inner grid may sometimes be big so a  around it is needed and it should be changed to

```
<Grid>
     <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid x:Name="innerGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
     <ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

but this should not always happen. I'm thinking to create a dependency property and based on the value if it's true then i will add  and false stay the same as before. 
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't see how an empty `Grid` will ever have the need for scrolling. That said, just leave the ScrollViewer there, with the ScrollBars' visibilities set to "Auto", they'll hide themselves if not needed.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to show the scrollbar only when the content is too large for one page you can use this:

```
<Grid>
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid />
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```